# Call middleware component by condition Asp.Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, middleware

Is it possible to only execute middleware for requests that comes not from js. Because i have a middleware executing of which doesn't make much ssense for js requests to my server.
Are there possible ways to check that request is not direct?

Comment: Are the two requests the same, same origin, same context? Do they differ somehow?

Comment: well you can add a customer header to your js calls and filter them out inside your custom middleware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot execute a middleware only for some requests, but you can check for the request to meet a condition in your middleware for exemple if an header is present in the request.

Let's say your js client calling your api add a custom header in each request you can write a middleware checking for that header and executing some code if the header is present.

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.Any(h => h.Key == "Custom-Header"))
    {
           DoStuff();
    }

    return next();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

For executing middleware for specific request, you could try [MapWhen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#use-run-and-map).

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.MapWhen(context => context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("branch"),
                           HandleBranch);

    app.Run(async context =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello from non-Map delegate. <p>");
    });
}
```

For checking whether handing the requests, implement your own logic to replace `context.Request.Query.ContainsKey("branch")`.